# OAuth2: client_credentials to register user

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

A web service uses OAuth2. I need to create a user. As I understand registration process looks like:

1. User fills a registration form, clicks "send"
2. An app gets token via POST oauth2/token (with grant_type=client_credentials)
3. The app creates user via POST api/user (with obtained token)

I'm interesting in 2nd step. The POST method assumes sending of client_id=CLIENT_ID & client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET. How to define those CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET?

Comment: In OAuth2 the `client_id` and `client_secret` are two properties that are shared between a client application and the OAuth issuer. They are used by the client application to prove its identity against the issuer and allow it to retrieve access tokens. What exactly would you like to know about them in particular?

Comment: So, firstly, how does a client get correct `client_id` & `client_secret`?

Comment: It gets one from the OAuth 2 issuer. Each OAuth issuer must have a way for registering client applications. Google, Facebook, LiveID, Twitter, ... all of them allow you to register a client application and obtain a `client_id` and a `client_secret`. If an OAuth issuer doesn't have a mechanism for registering client applications, then he would be a very lonely issuer as he would keep his tokens for himself :-) So basically it will depend on the OAuth issuer. Some of them provide nice GUIs where clients can register and obtain the necessary information, others might have REST API, ...

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? By the way, I very strongly suggest you reading the [OAuth 2 specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) if you intend to be doing some work in this domain.